# Missing form parameter: grant_type IONIC CAPACITOR

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, keycloak

I'm trying to call Keycloak, but the console gives me this error:

> MISSING FORM PARAMETER: GRANT_TYPE

This is my code:

```js
post() {
    debugger;
    let url = "http://172.20.10.3:8080/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token";
    CapacitorHttp.request({
      method:"POST",
      url:url,
      headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      data:{'username':this.username,
            'password':this.password,
            'grant_type':'password',
            'client_id':'myclient',
            'client_secret':'fk8oMLpTwdv98zBuhoWd11QWyZlojYsV',
            'claim':'normal_user'
          }
    }).then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
      this.dataReceived = JSON.stringify(res.data.access_token);
    })
  };
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are sending the data not in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST#example.

So your request should look something like this

```
post() {
  debugger;
  let url = "http://172.20.10.3:8080/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token";
CapacitorHttp.request({
    method:"POST",
    url:url,
    headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data:'username=' + this.username
        + '&password=' + this.password
        + '&grant_type=' + 'password'
        + '&client_id=' + 'myclient'
        + '&client_secret=' + 'fk8oMLpTwdv98zBuhoWd11QWyZlojYsV'
        + '&claim=' + 'normal_user'
      }
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
    this.dataReceived = JSON.stringify(res.data.access_token);
  })
};
```